# Response body unchanged after being processed by middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin-middleware

I am trying to write a middleware that calls the next middleware and then whatever the response body of that middleware is, it will be changed by my middleware.

This is what the `Configuration()` method in the `Startup` class looks like:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Use<OAuthAuthenticationFailCustomResponse>();
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
}
```

This is the middleware written by me:

```
public class OAuthAuthenticationFailCustomResponse : OwinMiddleware
{
    public OAuthAuthenticationFailCustomResponse(OwinMiddleware next)
        : base(next)
    {
    }

    public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        var stream = context.Response.Body;

        using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
        {
            context.Response.Body = buffer;

            await Next.Invoke(context);

            buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World");
            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            context.Response.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            buffer.SetLength(0);
            buffer.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            buffer.CopyTo(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I still receive the response of the `OAuthBearerAuthentication` middleware after calling the API, which is:

> {
>       "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request." }

[This](http://mitzen.blogspot.com/2016/12/owin-component-modifying-owin-response.html) is where I learnt to write the code that changes the response body;

Comment: You did not put the original stream back into the context response body

Answer (score 0):

The original stream was not put back into the context response body

```
public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context) {
    // hold a reference to what will be the outbound/processed response stream object 
    var stream = context.Response.Body;

    // create a stream that will be sent to the response stream before processing
    using (var buffer = new MemoryStream()) {
         // set the response stream to the buffer to hold the unaltered response
        context.Response.Body = buffer;

        // allow other middleware to respond
        await Next.Invoke(context);

        // we have the unaltered response, go to start
        buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // read the stream from the buffer
        var reader = new StreamReader(buffer);
        string responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();

        //...decide what you want to do with the responseBody from other middleware

        //custom response
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World");

        //write custom response to stream
        stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        //reset the response body back to the original stream
        context.Response.Body = stream;
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        context.Response.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I got: {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}Hello World. It seems like the string is just appended to the original response body.

Comment: Are you trying to replace the response body or alter it?

Comment: I am trying to replace the response body. The expected response body is "Hello World".

Comment: The following line threw System.NotSupportedException with message "Specified method is not supported.": stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

Comment: @KhanhCTG then just remove it.

Comment: The expression stream.Length threw the same exception like above. I have replaced it with byteArray.Length, however it still does not work. The response body is still: {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}Hello World.